# How to download output of PPL command?

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

The quickstart guide has an image of PPL page.

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/ppl/

There is a "Download" drop down button in the screen. I do not see that option.  SQL query output has that Download button, but PPL does not. I am using 7.9 version of Amazon Elasticsearch server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ppl doesn’t support download yet, reporting features will be added to ppl soon on the query workbench. Please add an issue on the repo to track.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/pipe-processing-language/issues/5

Comment: PPL is awesome, by the way :)